# boost_python-mt.so not available

Tags: linux, boost

I'm going to write my program which uses boost_python regardless to its version. Since the program is multithreaded, I must use libboost_python-mt. The thing is that when I install libboost_python-dev, I do not see libboots_python-mt.so in /usr/lib while following libraries exist:

```
libboost_python-mt-py27.so
libboost_python-py27.so.1.48.0
libboost_python.so
```

I'm using ubuntu 12.04, and I installed libboost_python-dev, libboost-all-dev

Answer (score 0):

The `-mt` suffix had been removed. The installed Boost libraries are multi-threading safe ([from this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486006/cannot-find-boost-thread-mt-library).)

Change the link flag from `-lboost_python-mt` to `-lboost_python` instead.